# Simplificar consulta LINQ com Contains

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Tenho duas questões com relação as consultas LINQ abaixo:

```
{    
    //lista de itens do orçamento
    var ids = itensOrcamento.Select(p => p.Id); 
    //Produtos - todos produtos cadastrados
    var produtos = Produtos.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id)); 
}
```

1. Com relação a `Produtos.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id))` não consegui interpretar exatamente a função `p => ids.Contains(p.Id)`, ou seja, como descrever esta função (o que ela faz)?
2. A segunda questão é se esta consultas podem ser otimizadas/melhoradas (juntando em uma consulta única)

Comment: Com relação a primeira, você não sabe o que o `Contains` faz? Me parece que sabe para usá-lo. Então não sei qual é a dúvida. A segunda depende do contexto, mas parece que não tem o que fazer.

Comment: Estou confuso com relação ao `Contains`, pra mim seria `p.Contains`, ou seja produtos contêm algo. Por isso gostaria de entender `Contains` neste contexto. @bigown

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primeiro vamos entender o **SQL** que cada uma delas gera:

O `contains` é um `WHERE id in ()`. Ao executar uma consulta assim:

```
db.TABELA.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.ID)).ToList();
```

O SQL gerado é assim:

```
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[CAMPO] AS [CAMPO]
    FROM [esquemateste].[TABELA] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] IN (cast(1 as bigint))
```

Diferente do `SELECT` que na verdade só filtra as colunas que irão retornar:

```
db.TABELA.Select(p=> p.ID ).ToList();
```

Vai gerar o seguinte SQL:

```
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID]
    FROM [esquemateste].[TABELA] AS [Extent1]
```

**RESUMINDO**

O seu primeiro caso ele irá pegar TODOS os registros da tabela, mas somente irá retornar a coluna ID.
O seu segundo caso vai retornar todas as colunas da tabela onde o `id` existe em uma coleção de IDs.(`Where(p => ids.Contains(p.ID))`)

**MELHORANDO**

Se eu entendi bem o que você está fazendo é pegar os detalhes dos produtos cadastrados em um orçamento. Com certeza você está indo para o caminho certo de juntar as duas, ir apenas uma vez no banco de dados é sempre (99,9% das vezes) melhor que ir duas vezes.

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
 var prods = (from io in db.itensOrcamento
              join p in db.protudo on p.ID equals io.ID
             where io.ID_DA_VENDA = XXX
            select p).ToList();
```

Dessa forma você faz um `join` das duas tabelas pelo mesmo ID sendo pego na sua primeira consulta e usado na segunda.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Corrigindo uma questão na resposta segundo o comentário do @TobyMosque. A implementação da pergunta realmente não vai duas vezes, ao fazer minha resposta levei em consideração o uso do `.ToList()` que coloquei no primeiro SQL feito por mim, depois disso eu não voltei a atenção a questão que a implementação da pergunta não tem esse `.ToList()`

No caso de se utilizar o `join` (que coloquei na resposta) ou o `in` (que está na pergunta) a performance é a mesma.

O ganho de performance seria apenas se você for duas vezes no banco de dados o que seria fazer isso aqui: (que é diferente do que está sendo feito na pergunta)

```
var t = db.TABELA.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.ID)).ToList();
var produtos = Produtos.Where(p => p.id = t.id).ToList();
```

Isso gera duas idas ao banco de dados porque ao executar o `.ToList()` ele vai executar a consulta.

Comment: não acho que a implementação deve vá duas vezes no banco de dados, afinal o `itensOrcamento.Select(p => p.Id);` não está realizando nenhuma consulta, está apenas preparando uma consulta que seja utilizada como parte da segunda. quanto a perfomance, pelo menos no SQL Server não existe vantagem em usar o JOIN, como pode ser visto no seguinte link: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: Perfeito comentário. Com certeza absoluta não tem diff entre join e exists, enquanto escrevia a resposta eu voltei a atenção a minha explicação e esqueci que ele não usa o `.ToList()` na primeira query da implementação dele. Fiz uma atualização na minha resposta. Obrigado pela correção.

Answer (score 3):

É difícil responder algo sem conhecer o contexto real. Ao que parece o código está pegando todos os `ids` dos itens de orçamento. Tenho minhas dúvidas se é isso que queria, mas está fazendo isto.

Depois ele pega cada um dos produtos existentes em algum lugar e procura o `id` de cada produto na lista de `ids` encontrados nos item de orçamento. Me questiono se esses `ids` têm alguma relação com o `id` de produto, deveria ter, mas é esquisito. Se não tiver, não vai dar certo. Se tiver, a organização parece estranha.

Não pode ser `p.Contains()` porque `p` é apenas um dado escalar, o código tem que verificar em uma coleção de dados. `p` é o produto da vez a ser analisado, não é todos os produtos, `p` é um elemento, `p`, não é o mesmo que `produtos`.

O [`Contains()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_) sempre analisa o conteúdo de uma coleção e diz se um dos elementos é o que está procurando. É uma busca que não interessa qual é o elemento, e sim se existe ou não, o retorno é booleano.

O corpo do `Contains()` equivaleria mais ou menos a isso:

```
foreach (var item in ids) if (item == p.Id) return true;
return false;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/ContaisLowered.cs).

Não vejo como otimizar isto. As duas operações são distintas, em objetos distintos. A não ser que em um contexto maior dê para descobrir algo extra ou que tem algo errado. Mas duvido que dê. Só tenho dúvidas se está fazendo o pretendido, aí é outro problema.

A resposta aceita é bastante ineficiente por usar abusivamente o `ToList()` portanto não use isto, curiosamente a tentativa de melhorar piorou o resultado.